# Rotate sphere texture Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am rendering a sphere via three.js and when I apply a texture it works just fine.
However, the equation I'm using to make markers isn't something I can play around with.
How can I rotate a texture on a sphere so that I can align the image according to the marker positions? specifically in the x direction.

Problem...Markers should be over Kagoshima, Japan and Hong Kong, China [image: Markers should be over Kagoshima, Japan and Hong Kong, China]

Should Be....and No I did not solve it...this is what it should look like not how it is now[image: No I did not solve it...this is what it should look like not how it is now]

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 40, 30);

    shader = Shaders['earth'];
    uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader.uniforms);

    uniforms['texture'].texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/images/world5.png');
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping; // This causes globe not to load
    texture.offset.x = radians / ( 2 * Math.PI ); // causes globe not to load
    material = new THREE.MeshShaderMaterial({

          uniforms: uniforms,
          vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
          fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader

        });
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    scene.addObject(mesh);
```

Comment: `MeshShaderMaterial` has been deprecated. It is now `ShaderMaterial`. Are you copying outdated code from the net -- or from an outdated book? Learn from the three.js examples that work with the current version of the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To shift the texture a certain number of `radians` of longitude, use this pattern:

```
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping; // You do not need to set `.wrapT` in this case

texture.offset.x = radians / ( 2 * Math.PI );
```

three.js r.58

Comment: I tried using the code you mentioned and the globe doesn't load at all. I've attached the code I'm using to create the sphere and append the texture.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question you asked. If you are having additional problems with your code, then please make a new post, with preferably a live example, and ask a specific question.

Comment: @Markus Proctor. Long time since your question but FYI this solution works OK for me (when trying to rotate texture on a cylinder in three.js R83).  Perhaps you omitted to define the variable "radians" in your code.

Comment: I offsetted a map of earth using this method and noticed this artifact: https://i.imgur.com/FoGl3Ox.png

Comment: UPDATE: Please ignore the comment above -- I discovered you need to offset the bump and specular maps by the same amount.

Answer (score 1):

To shift texture have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532197/shift-texture-on-sphere-three-js), this is another solution that worked for me.