# Shift texture on sphere Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have a sphere with a map on it using **Three.js**, the image dimensions are 1024*2048.

Here is the issue : I have CircleGeometries on my sphere indicating some places of interest, but when I just load the image on sphere it isn't well placed, and my points of interest aren't above the right country.

the idea is to rotate a bit my map so it fits the points of interest, but I can't get it to work.

I tried to use `texture.offset.x = 0.5;`

Math.PI / (2 * Math.PI) = 0.5 as I want to rotate half a globe

but I ended up with only half a globe covered with the image.

So I used `texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;`
but now I got like 2 images on each other on the globe and the result is quite ugly.

I looked the post about [rotate sphere texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577853/rotate-sphere-texture-three-js) to find help but it doesn't solve my problem. 
Btw is it mandatory to have a power of two image ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used the phiStart attribute of my sphere :

> phiStart — specify horizontal starting angle. Default is 0.

And set it to

**3/2 * Math.PI**  (instead of 0) **- (Math.PI/200)** to match exactly the country bounding box, as :

the images were around 100km far from their right position, then simple math can solve this :

2*PI = 40.000 km and I want 100km so 2*PI*100 / 40.000 = **PI/200**

Answer (score 0):

Use texture.mapping instead of texture.offset

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess this is a good advice but I don't have any knowledge about this, do you have relevant links I could have a look to ?